# How to produce a table with icons in an html doc. created with rmarkdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, kable

I want to create an html report with a table with icons (arrows) but while it works for shiny or flexdashboard it does not seem to wotk when I knit to html format. Is there a way to produce such a table in html output?

````
---
title: "Leads Report"
output: html_document
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,fig.width = 14)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
FCB<-c(5,6,4,6,8)
TWI<-c(3,5,2,3,5)
IN<-c(2,1,1,1,1)
DF1<-data.frame(FCB,TWI,IN)

FCB<-c(0,0,1,2,4)
TWI<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
IN<-c(1,3,4,5,6)
DF2<-data.frame(FCB,TWI,IN)

DF1$direction <- ifelse(DF2$FCB-DF1$FCB > 0, 
                     paste("<p>&#8593;</p>"), 
                     ifelse(DF2$FCB-DF1$FCB  < 0, 
                            paste("<p>&#8595;</p>"), 
                            paste("<p>&#8646;</p>")))
```

#### Table

```{r plot1, echo=FALSE,results='hide', message=FALSE, warning=FALSE }

knitr::kable({DF1}, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x,escape = F)

```
````

Comment: What errors do you get when knitting to HTML? It might just be a case of the font in the HTML format not supporting the particular characters you're using.

Comment: I get no errors I jus get nothing where the table should have been

Comment: `{DF1}` should not be in braces - I'm not quite sure what that's doing but it should just be `DF1`

Comment: that does not change something

Comment: Just noticed you have `results='hide'` in the chunk options - that will prevent the output from showing up.

Comment: oh I was using ot to hide warnings but yes it worked thanks