# How to use icons together with kable

Tags: r, shiny, kable

Working on a shiny app (without `rmarkdown`), I would like to add a visual representation of a column to my data table. Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59940453/216064), I produced

```
dat <- data.frame(
    what=letters[1:15],
    value=rnorm(15)
) |> transform(
    direction=ifelse(abs(value)<0.1, "&#8646;", ifelse(value<0, "&#8595;", "&#8593;"))
) |> knitr::kable(format="html", escape=FALSE) |>
    kableExtra::kable_styling() # show in browser
dat
```

which looks like this

[image: Table with Ampersand]

However, I would rather use `shiny::icon("circle-up")` like this:

```
down <- as.character(shiny::icon("circle-down")) # dropping as.character results in an error
up <- as.character(shiny::icon("circle-up"))
side <- as.character(shiny::icon("circle-right"))
dat <- data.frame(
    what=letters[1:15],
    value=rnorm(15)
) |> transform(
    direction=ifelse(abs(value)<0.1, side, ifelse(value<0, down, up))
) |> knitr::kable(format="html", escape=FALSE) |>
    kableExtra::kable_styling() # show in browser
```

but in this case, nothing is displayed:

[image: Table with Icons]

Any ideas how to use icons together with `kable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're rendering to html:

- Force shiny to load the icon deps by including a hidden sample icon anywhere in the document.

Here's a reprex:

[image: Icon showcase]

````r
---
title: "Icons"
output: html_document
date: "2023-07-20"
---

```{r}
up <- shiny::icon(name = "circle-up") |>  as.character()
down <- shiny::icon(name = "circle-down") |> as.character()
side <- shiny::icon(name = "circle-right") |> as.character()
dat <- data.frame(
  what = letters[1:15],
  value = rnorm(15)
) |> 
  transform(
    direction = ifelse(abs(value) < 0.1, side, ifelse(value < 0, down, up))
  ) |> knitr::kable(format = "html", escape = FALSE) |>
  kableExtra::kable_styling() # show in browser
dat
```

<!-- This will force shiny to load the icon deps: -->
```{r include=FALSE}
shiny::icon("circle-up")
```
````

Comment: For me this works without `runtime: shiny`.

Comment: This is great, I will try and figure out how to get it working in an shiny app.

Comment: @stefan That's interesting. I can't figure out why it doesn't work on my end if I don't force the icon deps.

Comment: Just to make sure: The deps are needed, i.e. adding the "invisible" `shiny::icon` is necessary. (: But for me your code works fine in a standard Rmd too without using `runtime: shiny` in the YAML header.

Comment: @stefan What version of rmarkdown are you using? I'm on 2.23.

Comment: My version of `rmarkdown` is `2.23` too.

Comment: @stefan Ahaa, I see what you meant. I've edited the answer.